# Nginx Serving Static Files Way Too Slowly

Tags: nginx

I asked this on Stack Overflow, but maybe it's more of a question for the SF crew.

So there have been lots of articles like [this one](http://www.codysoyland.com/2010/jan/17/evaluating-django-caching-options/) recently, extolling the virtues of Django Static Generator when used in combination with a light front-end Web server. It makes a whole lot of sense to me.

However, I get nothing like the results that other people are reporting -- thousands of requests per second -- and I don't know why that is.

I'm getting ready to launch a redesign of my newspaper's Web site. I've got it using Static Generator on a test server right now. And when I run Apache Bench on a particular static page, I get pretty miserable results:

`ab -c 10 -n 1000 http://journal.streamlister.com/news/`

```
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   53.011 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      21281212 bytes
HTML transferred:       21067360 bytes
Requests per second:    18.86 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       530.107 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       53.011 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          392.04 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

I'm watching `top` on the server while the siege is on, and I can see that it's not hitting Apache or the database server at all. So it is, in fact, serving the cached page. Nginx is running, but it never gets above 2% memory usage. CPU remains about 95 percent idle.

What am I doing wrong? Could I have misconfigured nginx somehow? My main config file is pasted below; the include specific to this site is pretty much a carbon copy of the sample config on the [Static Generator home page](http://superjared.com/projects/static-generator/). I'm running Ubuntu 9.10 on a Slicehost 256k slice.

```
user not_my_real_username;
worker_processes  4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  8192;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;
    keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can increase nginx performance, just adding next options to config:

```
   http {

      open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=300s;
      open_file_cache_valid 360s;
      open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
      open_file_cache_errors off;

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation also? Why this solution should work and what else?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx is actually serving files at a reasonable rate. From an external machine, I was able to get 371 requests per second with `ab` on one of the CSS files on that page.

You are testing the whole page, which means you're making 22 requests on it. I was able to get around 40 requests per second when benching `http://journal.streamlister.com/news/`.

It could probably be faster, but you're on a VPS where you're sharing CPU and disk I/O with others.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks. My speeds are still much slower than yours, but this gives me some hope. I didn't realize that `ab` would also pull down static media embedded in the page.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with gekkz that it might be your VPS. I just did an ab test on one of my static files and got:

Total transferred:      11203000 bytes
HTML transferred:       10861000 bytes
**Requests per second:    674.14** [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       14.834 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.483 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          7375.39 [Kbytes/sec] received

this was a css file. I'm also on a VPS from linode.com. A recent blog post of theirs shows [some tests](http://blog.linode.com/2009/12/04/linode-stomps-competition-in-performance-benchmark/) done on various VPSs that might be of interest.

I just looked and my config file is only a little different. I have 2 procs setup, 1024 connections and I have keep_alive turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Your test parameters are the problem I think. With a max concurrency of 10, but each page taking ~500 ms total to deliver, you will see at most about 20 requests per second.

Have you tested with higher concurrency levels using ab? (Note that ab is a really simplistic tool for load testing a web application, and can only really be considered a "microbenchmark"). You should also be benchmarking from a different machine of course, perhaps more than one other machine if bandwidth or memory are an issue.